# nginx / 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: nginx

When I'm trying to upload a file on my server I get this error:

413 Request Entity Too Large

Which ofcourse means my file is too large. So i've done a quick google search and came accross this:

open:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Edit:

```
# set client body size to 2M #
client_max_body_size 2M;
```

However I don't have that code in my nginx.conf file? Did this recently change? Can't find nothing about it

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`client_max_body_size` default value is 1 MB. [RTM](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Comment: Nvm, I had to I added the line myself, and now it works. Thanks