# uploading a picture error - payload too big

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-native

so i'm doing this project i got in React - and i need to upload a picture (and send it to the Database - express)
im using file Reader and sending base64 string to the server ( i have npm that converts it to photo)
it works perfect but i do have 1 problem, it only lets me upload small pictures / low quality images , and if the picture is too big , i get this error -

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413
>   (Payload Too Large)

what can i do to fix it and let it send bigger pictures?

my code in React -

```
async fileLoader(ev){
        if(ev.target.files[0]){
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var files = ev.target.files;
            let res = await reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            debugger;
            var newFileName = files[0].name
            setTimeout(()=>{
                this.setState({fileData:reader.result , fileName:newFileName})
            }, 30)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a response from your server that is managing the file upload.

What HTTP server is in front of the database?

For NGINX see:
[nginx / 413 Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182944/nginx-413-request-entity-too-large)

You may also need to find where the maximum file upload limits are in your node.js application.

Comment: how can i find where are the file upload limits?

Comment: What is the backend, where you are uploading the image to? You will be calling a URL for the image upload request, where is that hosted?

Comment: im uploading the image to uploads folder which found in Public folder in my express project.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374238/how-to-limit-upload-file-size-in-express-js

Comment: The previous link sent seems to be for an older version of Express. I assume you are on the latest, current version 4. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660542/10933704